# Font wasn't applied when setting TextAppearanceSpan to SpannableStringBuilder for api 26 and below

Tags: android, android-typeface, spannablestringbuilder

I'm trying to set a TextAppearanceSpan to SpannableStringBuilder.
It works for API 27 and above, but I can't find a solution for api 26 and below.
Here is the code i'm using:

```
fun getMenuSpannable(context: Context, title: String): SpannableStringBuilder {
    return SpannableStringBuilder(title).apply {
        setSpan(TextAppearanceSpan(context, R.style.TextAppearance_Theme_Subtitle1), 0, title.length, 0)
    }
}

<style name="TextAppearance.Theme.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="typeface">MacanRegular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/macan_regular</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/macan_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="lineSpacingMultiplier">1.4</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">-0.04</item>
</style>
```